# Using SSL for a single request

Tags: tls, aes

I want to use distributed cluster configured like: xx.resource.server.com.
xx - can be anything from aa to zz, most of the requests will be one time.

I need the connection to be secure between client and server, so I was thinking of using multidomain SSL certificate, to be safe from ears dropper, but from my understanding this would require establishing SSL connection on every request, which is costly and inefficient.

Is there an effective way to share SSL established key for aa.resource.server.com and ab.resource.server.com?
Is it better, just to use shared key, established with SSL protected server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a client is connecting to a different domain, then it's a different SSL session, regardless of whether or not it's the same key. Since the domain is different, there's no guarantee as to whether its the same server or not, so a different connection is required.

If you want to re-use the connection, then *don't close the connection*. If this is HTTP (you didn't specify) than you can do this using keep-alive, but typically only if you're using the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

the only implementations of ssl-session-cache i know of is instance-only; means: the ssl-session-store is accessed by multiple workers/threads, but not shared between servers or even via network.

if your data is not sensitive you migth switch to a lesser expensive cipher-suite to speed up connection.